# How to upload a file in android without php?

Tags: android, file-upload

I want to upload a file in android and later one should able to download it.I've seen some examples and mostly everyone using PHP server to upload a file.My question is is it possible to uplaod a file without php? If so can anyone show me some examples with out using php as i don't have any idea on php i'm not able to create a php server for upload.I hope my question is clear.

Thank you.

Comment: If you not have server, then where u want to upload the files from android

Comment: If u Not Use PHP then Use JAVA Webservice but any one is compalsory 4 upload file...

Comment: @ChiragPatel hi i can use .net web service also wright?

Comment: its Good bt i hav't More Idea About .net..i send more link is more help full 2 u..http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/            http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can Use `Dropbox` API to upload a file in Android

Read [`Upload a file using Dropbox api`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/files#android)